# R extract raster function not working

Tags: r, extract, raster

I am having trouble with the extract function in the raster package. The raster is not empty, but when I perform the extract function all the values come back as NAs. I can plot the points over the raster fine and they show up in the same location.

```
library(dismo)
library(raster)

#Import CSV File
file <- paste("C:/Michelle/Michelle/R/CuskPA_Sept12_2013_1.csv", sep=" ")

#read file
cusk <- read.table(file, header=TRUE, sep=',')
cusks<- subset(cusks, SlongDD!=0 & SlatDD!=0)
cuskll <-cusks[,24:25]

#import raster
salvar <- raster("C:/Michelle/Michelle/R/Variables/salvar")
ext <-extent(-67.6, -64.9, 41.0, 44.7453)
salvarc <-crop(salvar, ext)

#extract from raster   
psalvar <- extract(salvarc, cuskll)
```

This is what I get when I'm finished the extraction

```
head(psalvar)
[1] NA NA NA NA NA NA

summary(psalvar)
Mode    NA's 
logical    3859
```

The raster does not show up as empty.

```
> salvar
class       : RasterLayer 
dimensions  : 334, 240, 80160  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution  : 0.01121539, 0.01121539  (x, y)
extent      : -67.59662, -64.90493, 41.00048, 44.74642  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +no_defs 
data source : in memory
names       : salvar 
values      : 0.01655413, 2.137321  (min, max)
```

Here is an example of the lat/longs in the file

```
head(cuskll)
SlatDD   SlongDD
1 44.41533 -66.07883
2 44.41167 -66.07733
3 44.44883 -66.07433
4 44.47067 -66.01217
5 44.47050 -66.01183
6 44.47633 -66.01450
```

Comment: Have you tried coercing your data into an sp object? coordinates(cuskll) <- ~SlongDD+SlatDD

Comment: What does it look like if you plot it, pretty easy to see if you should be getting something. plot(salvar);points(cuskll);   It looks to me like you've mixed up Longitude with Latitude, so try cuskll <-cusks[,25:24] and proceed as before.

Comment: Can you plot, or otherwise work with `salvar` ? If so, then can you do the same with `csalvar` ?  And if that's OK, then the extraction step is almost certainly the culprit.

Comment: Thank you. They were backwards. I'd forgotten that R like Longitude first always.

Answer (score 3):

Put longitude first and latitude second